# Where to see the mapreduce code generated from hadoop pig statements

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

We all know that the hadoop pig statements are converted into java mapreduce code. I want to know there is any way i can see the mapreduce code generated from pig statements ?

Answer (score 11):

> We all know that hadoop pig statements are converted into java mapreduce code

This is not the case. Hadoop Pig statements are not translated into Java MapReduce code.

A better way of thinking about it is Pig code is "interpreted" in an Pig interpreter that runs in Java MapReduce. Think about it this way: Python and Perl do not "generate" C code, they run through a C program (interpreter) that executes the instructions. Basically, Pig provides a framework for a query plan to be executed. The Pig code gets interpreted and a prebuilt interpreter MapReduce job executes it. For this reason, this is impossible to do.

If you want to understand more of what is going on, use `EXPLAIN` and `ILLUSTRATE` to get some insight on the query plan that Pig built to execute your code.